# Page partially/fully hidden

Tags: html

I need to find out if a page(browser tab) is partially/fully hidden.
The page visibility api allows me to find paritally visible/ fully visible, fully hidden.

I need some way to find if page is partially/fully hidden.

http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#sec-document-interface

Comment: Am I understanding you right that you want to reach into the browser and interact with another tab (other than the page you are on)?

Comment: No. I need to know if some1 alt-tabbed the page. If he alt-tabs I need some javascript to run. I was hoping to use the above link's api for that

Answer (score 0):

This code may work

```
(function() {
    var hidden = "hidden";

    // Standards:
    if (hidden in document)
        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
        document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
        document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
        document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
    // IE 9 and lower:
    else if ('onfocusin' in document)
        document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
    // All others:
    else
        window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide 
            = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

    function onchange (evt) {
        var v = 'visible', h = 'hidden',
            evtMap = { 
                focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h 
            };

        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.type in evtMap)
            document.body.id = evtMap[evt.type];
        else        
            document.body.id = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHiddenProp(){
    var prefixes = ['webkit','moz','ms','o'];

    // if 'hidden' is natively supported just return it
    if ('hidden' in document) return 'hidden';

    // otherwise loop over all the known prefixes until we find one
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
        if ((prefixes[i] + 'Hidden') in document) 
            return prefixes[i] + 'Hidden';
    }

    // otherwise it's not supported
    return null;
}
```

For more details Plz refer [**this**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/) link

Comment: Hmmm. The page api considers partially visible as visible. I need to consider partially visible as hidden for my purposes. Thats what I meant by partially hidden/ fully hidden.